# ValueError: Input contains NaN, even when Using SimpleImputer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm trying to Work on the Titanic Dataset as my first Kaggle Project and I ran into this error. I kept searching for a solution here on Stack but i still can't figure it out.

I made the two Pipelines to preprocess the numerical and categorical features:

```
num_pipeline = Pipeline([
            ('imputer', SimpleImputer( strategy='median')), 
            ('scaler', StandardScaler())])
    
cat_pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),
        ('onehot', OneHotEncoder()) ])
```

and then i've joined them into a ColumnTransformer

```
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
        transformers = [
            ('num', num_pipeline, numeric_features),
            ('cat', cat_pipeline, categorical_features) ])
```

numeric_features and categorical_features being the list of numerical and categorical features:

```
numeric_features = ['Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Fare']
categorical_features = ['Pclass', 'Sex',  'Embarked']
```

Finally, in my final Pipeline I add a Classifier:

```
knn = Pipeline([
    ('Preprocessor' , preprocessor),
    ('Classifier', KNeighborsClassifier())
])
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Here is when I get the "ValueError: Input contains NaN"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
train.isna().sum()
```

Output:

```
PassengerId      0
Survived         0
Pclass           0
Name             0
Sex              0
Age            177
SibSp            0
Parch            0
Ticket           0
Fare             0
Cabin          687
Embarked         2
dtype: int64
```

The columns `Age`, `Cabin` and `Embarked` contain NaN values. However, you do not include the `Cabin` column in `numeric_features` or `categorical_features`, so it's values do not get imputed. This is why you get the error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried adding 'Cabin' to categorical_features and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @MedCh Can you do `preprocessor.fit_transform(X_train)`, and run `df.isna().sum()` on the result of it? This will show you which features still have NaN values

Comment: preprocessor.fit_transform(X_train) returns an array so counting null values return 0:

`count=0
for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in df[i]:
        if  np.isnan(i):
            count+=1
        i+=1
count`

Comment: I just noticed: your pipeline is called `knn` but you call `rf.fit()`. What is `rf`?

Comment: Sorry about that, it should be knn.fit(). I made a mistake while copying from Jupyter.

Comment: I ran your code using `train.csv` downloaded from Kaggle, and it didn't throw the ValueError. I'm not sure why it's happening for you

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem and found that restarting the kernel/Jupyter Notebook revealed the real issue. I forgot to update the y_train. So, I would suggest restarting the Jupyter Notebook if everything seems to be okay and you are still getting an error.